# Does ZFC's Axiom of Comprehension require second-order logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

Every source I've found so far says that first order logic is sufficient for defining ZFC set theory.

My lecture notes write the Axiom of Comprehension as follows:

> For any formula $\phi(x)$ with parameters and any set $y$, there exists a set $z$ whose elements are precisely those elements $x$ of $y$ that satisfy $\phi(x)$.

Does this first bit "for any formula $\phi(x)$" require second order logic? If so, why do people say first order is sufficient for ZFC? If not, is this just a metalinguistic use of "for any" and not "$\forall$"? What are the advantages in that case of deciding we'll use first order logic anyway (if not that it's weaker?)

Comment: There is no single "Axiom of Comprehension". That's why it is called the Axiom **Schema** of Comprehension. As a first order theory, ZFC contains one axiom for each instance of a formula $\phi$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If you choose to use second-order logic would it become only one axiom? Is having only one axiom instead of a potentially infinite schema useful in a non-superficial "regardless of complexity, numerically less axioms = better" sense?

Comment: Following on from Arturo's comment, this means that ZFC, like many first-order theories widely studied, contains infinitely many axioms. As far as I understand, second-order ZFC only has finitely many axioms, but it has several significant disadvantages, including lacking an effective proof procedure.

Comment: It doesn't require second order logic because at the end of the day, proofs are finitely long - and so only ever require finitely many instances of the comprehension axiom.

Comment: @MichaelCarey: a second order presentation of the comprehension axiom scheme as a single axioms gives a much stronger system. In second order logic, you can quantify over propositions, so despite the facts that proofs are finite, you can talk about infinitely many instances of the comprehension axiom.